# WPF MVVM design question

Tags: wpf, design-patterns, mvvm, class-design

In my View I have a TreeView with a event "TreeView_MouseLeftButtonDown". If it fires it proofs if the mouse clicked on a TreeViewItem. If not it deselects the last TreeViewItem.
My question is, should i do this in the code-behind or call a static methode in the viewmodel-class? How would you solve this?

The Methode:

```
private void treeView_MouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    if (sender != null)
    {
        var treeView = sender as TreeView;
        if (treeView != null && treeView.SelectedItem != null)
            TreeViewHelper.ReturnTreeViewItem(ref treeView, (XmlNode)treeView.SelectedItem).IsSelected = false;
    }
}
```

XAML:

```
<TreeView ... KeyDown="TreeView_KeyDown" 
              MouseLeftButtonDown="TreeView_MouseLeftButtonDown" 
              SelectedItemChanged="TreeView_SelectedItemChanged" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made for you solution using attached behaviors which were pretty well described here [Introduction to Attached Behaviors in WPF by Josh Smith](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/AttachedBehaviors.aspx)

My solution:

```
public static class TreeViewBehavior
{
    public static bool GetIsResetMouseLeftButtonDown(TreeView treeView)
    {
        return (bool)treeView.GetValue(IsResetMouseLeftButtonDownProperty);
    }
    public static void SetIsResetMouseLeftButtonDown(TreeView treeViewItem, bool value)
    {
        treeViewItem.SetValue(IsResetMouseLeftButtonDownProperty, value);
    }
    public static readonly DependencyProperty IsResetMouseLeftButtonDownProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown", typeof(bool), typeof(TreeViewBehavior),
        new UIPropertyMetadata(false, OnIsMouseLeftButtonDownChanged));
    static void OnIsMouseLeftButtonDownChanged(DependencyObject depObj, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        TreeView item = depObj as TreeView;
        if (item == null)
            return;
        if (e.NewValue is bool == false)
            return;

        if ((bool)e.NewValue)
        {
            item.PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown += OnMouseLeftButtonDown;
        }
        else
        {
            item.MouseLeftButtonDown -= OnMouseLeftButtonDown;
        }
    }
    static void OnMouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var tempItem = e.Source as TreeViewItem;
        if (tempItem != null && tempItem.IsSelected == false)
        {
            tempItem.IsSelected = true;
        }
        else
        {
            var tree = e.Source as TreeView;
            if (tree != null && tree.SelectedItem != null)
            {
                var selItem = (tree.SelectedItem as TreeViewItem);
                if (selItem != null)
                {
                    selItem.IsSelected = false;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and then in View you should add this:

```
<TreeView local:TreeViewBehavior.IsResetMouseLeftButtonDown="True">
```

I hope my solution do what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Wow, that is mega-complicated for such a simple thing.

Comment: I agree that it could be done in code-behind, but some people like having clean code-behind. My solution also gives opportunity to easy reuse behaviour in other treevies.

Comment: your deselect-function doesent work but the behavior works great. thx for your cost.

Comment: @myName what do you mean by telling that my deselect-function doesn't work? Are you sure that you are using my latest code?

Comment: I have bindet a Xml to my TreeView this is way i need a custom function for deselect ;-) Solved here: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5407650/how-to-select-a-databound-treeviewitem)

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to **add a behaviour** to the TreeView.

The way I would implement this would be using **Attached Properties**. I would create an attached property called `VerifiesLeftClick` or similar and implement the logic in there. This way you do not need an event in the code behind.

See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms749011.aspx) for samples.

Comment: **here** doesn't link to anything! I'm interested in the samples too :)

Comment: i have read the article and googelt for more but i don´t get through it :-( would be nice if you can show me the implementation on my problem :-)

Comment: @myName I was about to post my solution but code from Pawel looks correct.