# How to get the TabItems in a TabControl that has it's ItemsSource bound to a list?

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a TabControl that has tab bound to a List:

```
<TabControl ItemsSource="{Binding SomeList}" />
```

How can find the instances of TabItem?  I found other answers that suggest looking at the TabControl.Items list but that is full of Foos.  Any idea?

Comment: is using an ItemTemplate of any help?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That question gets asked pretty often and the answer always is: *Don't do it.*

In theory you should not *need* the `TabItem` instance because you should bind everything you need to modify. (Also in theory you could get the instance using the [`ItemContainerGenerator`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.itemcontainergenerator.aspx))

Comment: I have the tabcontrol bound such that some tabitems's visibility may switch to collapsed.  If that is the selected tab, I end up with a tab control that looks like no tab is selected.  I would like to never end up in that situation.  I'll see if I can come up with a more binding oriented solution.

Comment: What if it's a control in the tab content that you need? For instance, tab 2 has a listbox control for which I want to grab selected items? I can't necessarily bind selected items to a collection on the view model when the tabs are generated based on another bound collection. Or can I?

Comment: @Sinaesthetic: You commonly bind the selected items by binding the individual items' `IsSelected` property to the item's model/view-model, then you just filter your collection by the bound property.

Comment: In theory, end-user should be smart and UI should be intuitive enough. But In real world, It is NOT

Comment: @deathrace The point is: A lot of people approach problems the wrong way, because they do not know what the *intended* solution is in WPF. There can be legitimate reasons for getting the UI instance, but in the vast majority of cases you neither need to nor should access the instance.

Answer (score 13):

If, for example, you need to get the actual TabItem related to the SelectedItem (which is a bound object) you can use the [`ItemContainerGenerator`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.itemcontainergenerator.aspx) as H.B mentioned

```
var tabItem = this.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(selectedObject);
```

Comment: Thanks for actually ANSWERING the question instead of saying they no one should have to do that. In my case I want to disable the other tabs (without disabling content) when the user makes a change to one of them.

Answer (score 1):

Long time ago I had a similar problem with the treeview in wpf. I have solved it using `ItemContainerGenerator`. If you want you can have a look at my solution, maybe it helps you with your problem: [How to select a databound TreeViewItem?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5407650/how-to-select-a-databound-treeviewitem)

But i think H.B. is right with his statement: " [..] you should not need the TabItem instance because you should bind everything you need [..] "